# Is there any way to detect a table/column name change in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I'm using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables in MySQL to detect things like added/removed tables/columns, but one thing I don't think I can do with that method is detect when a table/column name is changed.

Specifically, if you were to observe the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables when a table/column name is changed, it would appear as if one table/column was deleted and another new one was added.

However, if I react to this addition/deletion like any other standard addition/deletion, then I'll end up deleting one table/column and all the data in it instead of simple changing the name of it, which I want to do.

As such, is there any way to detect table/column name changes in MySQL?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with information_schema, but I might be wrong. Depending on what your purpose is exactly, you might want to enable binlog and monitor that instead.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thank you, rlanvin. Do you know of any good resources for turning on binlog and monitoring it specifically for what I'm looking for? Thanks.